# Background Images from CSS not getting path in localhost but works directly when opened in browser

Tags: html, css

I have my stylesheet called in my html page and it has a 'background' image in it. When I open the HTML page  using localhost it doesn't show any image. But when the same HTML page is opened directly in FIREFOX it shows all the image. I used firebug to see the problem, and it shows that the path is invalid.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 -------
 --------- 
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Part

```
body {
    background: url(../images/bg-body.jpg) repeat;
    font-family: 'Conv_Ubuntu-Light';
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 960px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: are you on linux or windows...????if linux, this might be a `chmod` problem....

Comment: Would it be `background-image: url("images/bg-body.jpg");`?

Comment: @JunM : Tried that too; but din't work

Comment: @Roger : strange....have you checked your relative path to css, is that correct????try adding `100% 100%` in `background`...might be dimension issue!!

Comment: are you using .htaccess, if yes please try without it and also try this background: url(/images/bg-body.jpg)

Comment: @Neo: No. Its a simple HTML template.

Comment: @NoobEditor: The Paths are correct. Its working fine as single HTML file ( I meant if I open it directly without localhost it works; but not in localhost).

Comment: @Roger this is strange, can you explain the directory structure or show us the image of it?

Comment: @Roger : is page live somewhere???can you show it...or give a complete fiddle of ur css!

Comment: May be try to clean cache?

Comment: @ALL : Thanks guys solved it just now. Don't know the reason though. Copied the whole files and folder into a new folder and its working :). Sorry to disturb you guys through out the day.

Comment: I had the same problem, pretty much, until I replaced `background: url("file.png") no-repeat;` with these two lines: `background-image: url("file.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your codes localhost not getting the path what you have described because the particular file is not located there.
copy all your related files to `C:\\wamp\www` directly. once files are copied there your problem will be solved.

Comment: I think thats not the problem. The page is loading fine in localhost except the images thats been called from CSS file like 'background: url(../images/bg.jpg) repeat'

Comment: even i faced the same problem while fetching data from xml. the final value never showed up on localhost but it works on the web server. i have issued with my network in the office premises.